# JSON parser that is lazy about parsing numerics?

Tags: c, json

Anyone know of a C based JSON parser that allows me to access the string representation that came in for number fields?  Example of what I mean:

```
json_t * dist = json_object_get(coord, "accuracy");
snprintf(dataOut->distance, MAX_COORD_LEN, "%f", json_number_value(dist));
```

This is silly and difficult to write unit tests for.  I would prefer to simply call `json_string_value(dist)` and get exactly the string that came in for that number.  I would prefer further that it didn't bother converting that string into a number.  That way when I feed my routine a test string containing "54.6045" for that field I get "54.6045" back and not some padded or rounded value...and I don't need to ever parse the number because I'm never going to use it as one.

As far as I can tell, there's no such thing...which seems to me to be quite silly.  The above example is from Jansson and using the string value function returns null.

I would really prefer not having to write my own just because of this.

Comment: If you're just using it as a string, why don't you make it a string? Is it because you don't control the input?

Answer (score 2):

In case you didn't already know this, http://www.json.org/ maintains a list of JSON libraries written in a wide variety of languages, including 12 of them in C.

I'm using [jsmn](https://bitbucket.org/zserge/jsmn/wiki/Home) for a resource-constrained, embedded platform. All it does is tokenize JSON strings, so you could get what you need from that library, but you would need to construct a little more logic around it to do anything useful.

Similarly, you could probably adapt JSON_checker to do what you want.

If you can't find one that does what you want, it's not that hard to parse yourself.

Comment: I'll check it out.  That one scared me off because the documentation link points to 404.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/cesanta/frozen

There is an example in a README that shows exactly what you're asking for, here's a short version:

```
static const char *str = " { foo: { bar: [ 80, 443 ], baz: 1.2e-21 } } ";
struct json_token tokens[50];
int size = sizeof(tokens) / sizeof(tokens[0]);
const struct json_token *tok = NULL;

parse_json(str, strlen(str), tokens, size);
tok = find_json_token(tokens, "foo.bar[1]");
printf("My number is: [%.*s]\n", tok->len, tok->ptr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tiny-json is a C parser that allows you to access the string representation that came in for number fields by the simplest way. Just ask for a JSON property and it returns a pointer to null-terminated with the value. 
https://github.com/rafagafe/tiny-json

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tiny-json.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

    char str[] = "{\"accuracy\":654,\"real\":2.54e-3}";

    // In the example only 3 is needed. For root and two fields.
    json_t mem[ 3 ];

    json_t const* root = json_create( str, mem, sizeof mem / sizeof *mem );
    if ( !root ) {
        fputs( "Cannot create a JSON.\n", stderr );
        return 1;
    }

    { // You can get the primitive values as text format:

        char const* accuracy = json_getPropertyValue( root, "accuracy" );
        if ( !accuracy ) {
            fputs( "The filed 'accuracy' is not found.\n", stderr );
            return 1;
        }
        printf( "The accuracy value: %s\n", accuracy );

        char const* real = json_getPropertyValue( root, "real" );
        if ( !real ) {
            fputs( "The filed 'real' is not found.\n", stderr );
            return 1;
        }
        printf( "The real value: %s\n", real );

    }

    { // You can check the type of a field and get its value in binary format:

        json_t const* accuracy = json_getProperty( root, "accuracy" );
        if ( !accuracy ) {
            fputs( "The filed 'accuracy' is not found.\n", stderr );
            return 1;
        }
        if( json_getType( accuracy ) != JSON_INTEGER ) {
            fputs( "The filed 'accuracy' is not an integer.\n", stderr );
            return 1;
        }
        // Get the value in binary format:
        long long accuracyVal = json_getInteger( accuracy );
        printf( "The accuracy value: %lld\n", accuracyVal );
        // Get the value in text format:
        char const* accuracyTxt = json_getValue( accuracy );
        printf( "The accuracy value: %s\n", accuracyTxt );

        json_t const* real = json_getProperty( root, "real" );
        if ( !accuracy ) {
            fputs( "The filed 'real' is not found.\n", stderr );
            return 1;
        }
        if( json_getType( real ) != JSON_REAL ) {
            fputs( "The filed 'real' is not a real.\n", stderr );
            return 1;
        }
        // Get the value in binary format:
        double realVal = json_getReal( real );
        printf( "The real value: %f\n", realVal );
        // Get the value in text format:
        char const* realTxt = json_getValue( real );
        printf( "The real value: %s\n", realTxt );

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Jansson's a great library, and it would be a shame to choose another one based on unit testing. I'm not sure why you're opposed to parsing numeric values -- can you explain?

As far as your code snippet is concerned, you may be a little annoyed with the boilerplate involved in retrieving numeric values from your structure. I'd suggest you learn to love the json_pack / json_unpack functions. You can retrieve an integer element from a dictionary as follows:

```
double d;
json_unpack(coord, "{s:f}", "accuracy", &d);
```

Using this call, you don't have to work with the (json_t *) object that represents the floating-point value. You should, of course, check the json_unpack() call's return code for error conditions.

Comment: Why would someone answer a question about getting the string representation of a number from a JSON string and NOT parsing into double by showing a different way of reading into a double??